# Inclusive redstone repeater

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

So, I have this:

[image: Redstone Line]

Now, what I want is a repeater that would work *while keeping the unlit lamp on*.

Yeah, that one right there:

[image: This one!]

I have this already:

[image: My version]

...but the piston turns on and off repeatedly until the input is off.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're running the power along a row of raised blocks behind the lamps. This normally works because redstone on top of a block will power the block below it, and that block will power blocks adjacent to it. This is why the repeater is causing a "dead" spot: the repeater isn't powering the block below it, so nothing is powering that one lamp.

Instead of powering a row of blocks beside the lamps, power every second lamp directly. Directly powering a lamp will light both the directly-powered lamp and the two beside it, as the middle lamp powers its neighbours:

[image: A single redstone input powering three adjacent redstone lamps]

Because redstone in a line won't directly power an adjacent block, to do this in a line you have to have the redstone "bus" one block distant, with singleton lines going into every second block. This conveniently gives you a place to put your repeaters:

[image: Redstone lamps powered by a nearby redstone bus incorporating repeaters]

Of course you can also power every third block instead of every second and it will work the same. If redstone is no object I prefer the redundancy and simplicity of two-block spacing, but three-block spacing works better when redstone dust is a scarce commodity.

Comment: @PieCrust Bah, you're right. My redstoning is rusty.

Comment: @PieCrust Got a fix for you! Incoming...

Comment: Right, so this is clever. However, there are two issues: One, I'm trying to keep the design as compact as it is now. Two, I was only using the lamps for placeholders, in reality it's pistons facing away from the redstone.

Comment: I can send world file if you want so you can see what it really is.

Comment: @PieCrust Ah, yes, pistons are a non-opaque block and power differently. Possible to do, but unfortunately not as compact as you want and IIRC uses lots of repeaters.

Comment: Well, I kinda doubt that since I developed one on my own with only one flaw... Anyway, thanks for your help. I've upvoted your post in case anyone else may find it useful as it is quite so.

Comment: @PieCrust Next time when you ask a question, please include exact description of the problem you are facing.

Comment: @PieCrust Hey cool! Take pictures and post it as an answer? I haven't had mucking-with-Minecraft time necessary to update *this* answer for pistons, but if you've got an answer (especially if it's more compact than mine), you should self-answer this.

Comment: Well, I put it in the question, under *I have this already:*